# Ease-in function

Tags: functions

I need a function for ease-in effect, exactly like this [ease-in-out function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121720/ease-in-out-function), but without the end (infinite).

I've tried two variants that I don't like too much for a while.

The first one never becomes really straight. I'd prefer to have it absolutely or almost absolutely straight after some certain $x_1$ value.

$$
f(x)=x*(1-\frac{1}{x+1})
$$

Second one is a combination of two functions which works well (for $x_1=\frac{π}{2}$), but I don't like the fact that I have two functions instead of one.

$$
f_1(x)=1-cos(x), x<\frac{π}{2}
$$
$$
f_2(x)=x-\frac{π}{2}+1, x>=\frac{π}{2}
$$

Is there a better variant?

Comment: What do you mean by: "but without the end (infinite)."

Comment: I mean it should be completely straight from some point to the infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any ease-inout function $f(x)$ with $f(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$ and domain and range [0, 1], such as  the 
$$f(x,a)=\frac{x^a}{x^a+(1-x)^a}$$ suggestion from the other thread, you convert to ease-in only by "zooming" on the first half, i.e. use 2 * f(x/2).  Similarly, for an ease-out function zoom on the second half using 2 * f(1/2 + x/2) - 1.

Easy.  :-)

(You will lose the property that $f(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$, but I think that's not important for one-sided easing.)

Edit:  As described in my comment, you can patch in the line $y=a(x-1)+1$ at $x=1$ as shown in the following figure for $a=2$.  If you specifically need a gradient of 1, transform $x\rightarrow\frac{x}{a}$.

[image: Piecemeal function with $a=2$]

Comment: Thanks. The answer is not full. This is the easy part. The hard one is to continue this function with a straight line.

Comment: As others have said, a single function that is both linear and not is impossible.  Either you have a known range of $x$ and scale appropriately, or you construct the function in two parts.  For my answer, the slope at $x=1$ is $a$, so you can switch at that point to the line $y=a(x-1)+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an IF-THEN block:

Pseudo-Code:

```
IF x > 10 THEN
 return value
 ELSE:
 return f(x)
 ENDIF
```

Comment: If $x > x_1$ then I need a linear function $f(x)=N*x$

Comment: @raacer Yes, you can not have a function that is curved and straight at the same time it is not possible, see: definition of straight line. You have to use intervals, for example: ease-in function from 0 to 10 and straight from 10 to 20. You may instead use bezier curves as in this site: http://easings.net/en#easeInOutQuart

Comment: I've tried bezier curves but the resulting shape was not ideal. It seems the if/else variant is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is a good thought.  It can be written as $f(x)=x-\frac x{x+1}=x-1+\frac 1{x+1}=\frac{x^2}{x+1}$  This has an asymptote at $f(x)=x-1$ but doesn't approach it very quickly.  It seems like you want to start at $(0,0)$.  Your second example has the derivative at $0$ equal to zero. Do you want that? How sharp a corner is allowed?  There are functions that will satisfy any answer you give to these questions.  You might try $f(x)=x-\left (\frac {x}{x+k}\right)^n$ for some moderately large $n,k$ and see how you like it.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried a variant similar to you last suggestion but I don't like the result. Finally I've ended with if/else variant.